# Why is Django REST Framework giving a 403 Forbidden error to non-GET requests sent from every computer but my own?

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm currently developing a web app with a Django REST Framework API. It works perfectly on the computer that I developed the web app on (it is hosted online, not locally, so this seems odd to me), but then when I try logging onto the website from any other computer, all GET requests work perfectly well (the user authentication is working properly as well), but any POST, DELETE, or PUT requests made by the frontend to the API receive a 403 Forbidden error.

I'm using a React frontend and using the fetch API to make requests to the backend.

Here are the important parts of my settings.py file (the app is deployed using heroku):

```
import django_heroku

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['somehostdomain']

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    )
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://somedomain'
]

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Each frontend request looks something like this:

```
    someRequest(parameter) {
        let csrftoken = this.getCookie('csrftoken');

        fetch('https://somedomain/api/some-request/', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "parameter": parameter
            })
        })
    }
```

where the function getCookie just creates a csrftoken (this part isn't original code, it's widely used):

```
    getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
```

I think that the error either has something to do with CORS, or [Django REST Framework Permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) but nothing I have tried so far has worked.

I've tried manually putting allow any in rest framework permissions (this is the default behavior anyway so it didn't work):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Your origin whitelist is using http but your api is on https, is that correct?

Comment: Yea, but I think thats how its supposed to be. I've had it like that for a while, and I'm pretty sure that it works like that.

Comment: When I have https in the CORS whitelist, it doesn't work.

Comment: Also if that were the issue, wouldn't it effect me on both computers?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your csrftoken is set properly and passed along the request. The symptom seems your CSRF token is not working. DRF will require CSRF token present for POST/PUT/DELETE methods once you have logged in.

Comment: What could cause the csrftoken to not be configured properly on any other computer but working on mine? Any ideas? Because the fact that it works on my computer would mean that they are working somehow right?